# SQL Server - evaluation period has expired error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

Yesterday ended trial period of SQL Server 2014 installed on my PC. I decided to use express edition and uninstalled SQL Server 2014 and installed Express edition.

But when I open SQL Server Management Studio, there is still an error:

> evaluation period has expired

Afterwards I installed developer edition of SQL Server 2014 which is free now as I understood. The installation was successful but I still have the same error when I open SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I use Express or Developer edition version of SQL Server?

Thank you

Comment: You can **[extend SQL Server evaluation period](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/evaluation-period-expired-for-sql-server-2012-how-to-extend-it/)** without uninstalling the current SQL server or installing a new SSMS as mentioned at **[SQL Server Evaluation period has expired](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/evaluation-period-expired-for-sql-server-2012-how-to-extend-it/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the SSMS preview releases. They have the same features as previous versions with more bug fixes and better compatibility with Azure SQL databases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If someone stumbles across this thread, change the `Edition` under `Free Edition` to `Developer` and apply the changes.

You will find this feature at `SQL Server Installation Center` -> `Maintenance` -> `Edition Upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is one of the worst application when we talking about uninstall)
You should try to uninstall it again but this time do it much more scrupulously.

1. stop all instances and services of SQL Server (or skip this point)
2. simple uninstall SQL Server
3. install something like cCleaner and remove all other SQL Server files such as registry files and temp files
4. install new version only after full uninstall of previous version (+restart comp);

Good luck.

Comment: thank you! I just installed managment studio 2016 and at last it works))