# Replace SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Evalution with SQL Server Dev Edition

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have had SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Evaluation Edition that expired after 180 days, but now see that the SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition is free

Is there any way I can fully remove the Evaluation Edition and install the Developer Edition.  When I try, I get the message explaining my Evaluation period has expired, and visit the microsoft.com shop

many thanks

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399867/sql-server-evaluation-period-has-expired-error Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was an absolutely ball ache.  Try several combinations of procedures and the finally after a day this is what i would recommend

1. remove every component of SQL 2014 Enterprise (add/remove programs)
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\ConfigurationState\CommonFiles set to "3"
3. Install SQL Express (not developer edition - this seems to think i was re-installing Enterprise Evaluation)
4. Then upgrade to Developer edition